Supabase - Retrieving images urls from supabase storage and saving it to supabase table after upload
I'm creating a blog post with supabase auth, database and tables, where a blogger can post a blog.
This post contains the post details and upto 4 images.
How can I upload this details using uppy for images with resumable download, to the post table and at the same time save the urls of the images after the blogger uploads?
I'm able to upload the images to supabase storage, and i created and array attribute for image urls, i also set a trigger to call a function that updates the blog table after the upload with the  details, but this still runs into an error

Please update your question to include the error.

After more research on uppy, i manages to solve this issue.
try {
    uppy.upload().then(async (result) => {
      const description = blogDescriptionRef.current.value;
      const title = blogTitleRef.current.value;
      if (result.failed.length > 0) {
        toast.error("Image upload failed");
      } else {
        const imageUrls = result.successful.map((file) => file.uploadURL);
        const {
          data: { user },
        } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

        if (description.trim() && title.trim()) {
          const { error } = await supabase
            .from("posts")
            .insert({
              name: title,
              product_images: imageUrls,
              title: description,
            });

          if (error) throw error;
        }
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error("Error saving blog:");
  }


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
